# Big file compression with python

Tags: python, compression

I want to compress big text files with python (I am talking about >20Gb files).
I am not any how an expert so I tried to gather the info I found and the following seems to work :

```
import bz2

with open('bigInputfile.txt', 'rb') as input:
    with bz2.BZ2File('bigInputfile.txt.bz2', 'wb', compresslevel = 9) as output:
        while True:
            block = input.read(900000)
                if not block:
                    break
                output.write(block)

input.close()
output.close()
```

I am wondering if this syntax is correct and if there is a way to optimize it ? I have an impression that I am missing something here.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is the file you output correct?

Comment: Why did you choose to read by 900000?

Comment: Yes it seems, uncompressed size corresponds and the format looks ok. I am not confident with everything I code being learning python (and IT in general) by myself. Thanks. Yes I choose thinking about the size of the chunks used by bzip2, I thought better compress one chunk at a time, wrong ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your script seems correct, but can be abbreviated:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

with open('bigInputfile.txt', 'rb') as input:
    with bz2.BZ2File('bigInputfile.txt.bz2', 'wb', compresslevel=9) as output:
        copyfileobj(input, output)
```

Comment: Thank you ! So you mean the definition of the chunk sizes is not necessary then ?

Comment: Yep. `copyfileobj` copies in blocks of 16kB by default; you can still set the chunk size if you want by adding a third argument.

Comment: re: the chunk size: it probably isn't going to make a big difference to either processing time or compression ratio so unless you need to really eke out that last little bit, easiest to just leave it on the default.

Comment: An elegant Pythonic example.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the .close() methods? 
They are not needed as you use the with: statement.